# Custom validation of a user's e-mail for Django ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, validation

In my models I have setup a custom model (`CodeUser`) with a foreign key to the `User` model of `django.contrib.auth`. I am actually using `django-auth-ldap`, but the `User` model is the same. I then have a `Code` model which has a `custodian` field that is a foreign key to a particular `CodeUser`.

```
class CodeUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    # Other fields...

class Code(models.Model):
    custodian = models.ForeignKey('CodeUser')
    # Other fields...
```

I am using a `ModelForm` for the `Code` model and would like for the form to accept the e-mail address of the `CodeUser` for the `custodian` field. I think this can be done by simply using the `to_field_name` option of `ModelChoiceField`.

However, I would like the ability to create the User if they do not exist already. I do this by making an `LDAP` query to make sure the e-mail can be associated with a user and then using the `populate` method of `django-auth-ldap`.

The process of populating a user works fine, I am just having trouble in figuring out where this code should go in my django app. I attempted to create a custom field `class`, and then use that for the `field_classes` for the `custodian` field in the Code ModelForm. I implemented a custom `validate` method for my field, but this method never gets called during the `Code` ModelForm validation. It appears that validation is relegated to the model only for ModelForms.

```
class UserByEmailField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def validate(self, value):
        # Check e-mail is valid
        # Check user already exists or populate from LDAP

    def to_python(self, value):
        # Return CodeUser instance

class CodeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['custodian']
        field_classes = {'custodian' : UserByEmailField}
```

Finally, my question is, where should the code for `CodeUser` validation/population by e-mail address go?  There are a couple of other forms that need this process as well, so I thought that a custom field class made the most sense.

Comment: I think you could do with writing a [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/validators/#module-django.core.validators) I've never tried doing this with a modelchoicefield so I have no idea what `value` would be for the validator

Comment: I deleted my answer since it was essentially wrong, the `clean` method it referred to is supposed to call `validate`

Answer (score 0):

You can do in two different places.  You can override the change_form.html for the CodeForm and do it via JavaScript.

or what I have done in the past is do it in the ModelForm and override the "def clean" function. here is an example where I did it in a custom change password form.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(ChangePasswordForm, self).clean()
    oldpass = cleaned_data.get('oldpassword')
    if not self.user.check_password(oldpass):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid Password")
    pass1 = cleaned_data.get('password1')
    pass2 = cleaned_data.get('password2')

    if pass1 != pass2:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
```

should work in a ModelForm as well.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: Ok, this is somewhat along the lines of where the Django docs were leading me.  I just thought it would be less repetitive to keep it as part of a field so that I could use it in all the forms that needed this kind of validation/population.

Comment: There is a way to create your own custom ModelField (override the CharField... there is also an EmailField I believe you could modify).